# Two dots vs dirname(__DIR__) for require and other cases

Tags: php, performance, require

I've tried to find any information about it bit without any success.

What the difference between `/../` and `dirname(__DIR__)` for `require` statement and other cases? Maybe some performance research, popular code style recommendations or unexpected behavior?

Examples:

- `require __DIR__ . '/../file.php'`
- `require __DIR__ . '/../../file.php'`
- `require dirname(__DIR__) . '/file.php'`
- `require dirname(__DIR__, 2) . '/file.php'`

Consider several situations, for example if

- any side-effect could occur on symlinks
- `/../` could be disabled, e.g. in `php.ini` or somewhere else
- (and further thoughts)

Comment: There might be few situations where a path containing `/../` is not accepted for security reasons since some function is expected to be used with client input. `include`/`require` and most builtin filesystem functions do accept even unix path style on Windows hosts.

Comment: `/../` can be disabled in `php.ini`?

Comment: Another good point (I don't know such a setting). You might want to share an answer to your own question pointing out the actual ini-setting (and even accept it).

Comment: However, I've seen code bases in projects with functions restricting path parameters not to contain `/../`. Consider also `realpath` which requires the path to actually exist and then returns the corresponding absolute path.

Comment: I've added your thoughts from comments to the question as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The two serve the same function.

`dirname()`, according to the [official documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) given a file or directory path, it returns the parent directory, which is what `/../` also does.

I don't think a performance difference can be seen between the two, so it mostly comes down to personal preference.

Comment: What about symlinks? Is there the same behavior with them?

Comment: Yes, I did a few tests just to be sure and it appears the behaviour is identical for the two even when dealing with symlinks.

Comment: You are basically doing `require '/your/project/file.php'` vs `require '/your/project/dir1/../file.php'`, which will always point to the same file. Hope this makes sense :)